# What is the fundamental group of this complex surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X\subset A^3_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the affine complex surface defined by $x^r+y^s+z^t=0 $, and let $Y=X-(0,0,0)$. Here $r,s,t\geq2$ are positive integers.

Then what is the fondamental group of $Y$? What can we know from the map $f:Y\to A^2_{\mathbb{C}}-(0,0),\,\,\,x\mapsto x^r,y\mapsto y^s$ ?

Comment: Some possibly trivial observations. First, the fundamental group of $X$ and $Y$ are equal. Let us assume that $s=t=n>2$ (the greater than $2$ condition for simplicity). Then, we have a $\mathbb{G}_m$-fibration $Y\to Z:=V(x^n+y^n+z^n)\subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$. Thus, we get a long exact sequence

$$1=\pi_2(Z)\to\pi_1(\mathbb{G}_m)\to \pi_1(Y)\to \pi_1(Z)\to \pi_0(\mathbb{G}_m)=1$$

You know that $\pi_1(Z)$ is (since its a smooth surface of genus $n(n-1)/2$). You can perhaps do something similar for general $r,s,t$ by using weighted projective space.